# ADAL, Angular and WEB API strategy

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, adal.js

I am a Microsoft developer. Making an ASP.NET application with authentication to Azure AD is very easy. The traditional multi page application with Vue (as an example) can be created within two minutes (by using the Authentication wizard in Visual Studio). However watching some Angular and NPM videos I liked the CLI/npm approach. So I decided to build my next project using ADAL.js, ASP.NET Core API and Angular 6 (deploy to Azure web app). But I haven't been able to succeed, and have only been met by complexity and issues.

Is the combo of these three technologies just a bad mix, Visual Studio not suited for SPA, or have I just gotten a bad start? Any suggestions on a good setup? I am considering to split the API and front end in two apps, so I can use clean Angular without having to worry about who is building TypeScript (VS or Node) etc. But then I need two web apps, and have to worry about CORS. Any suggestions here, what is a good setup to get started?

I have followed a lot of articles like:
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-6-app-with-visual-studio-2017/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6

But all of them had issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this Microsoft published GitHub sample. This sample demonstrates the use of ADAL for JavaScript for securing an AngularJS based single page app, implemented with an ASP.NET Web API backend, that calls another ASP.NET Web API using CORS.

[Call an Azure AD protected Web API in an AngularJS Single Page App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/)